# How to install/symlink packages in monorepos from root node_modules in yarn workspace

Tags: npm, yarn-workspaces

I have to use the cached `node_modules` at root level and use it to add symlinks to all the mono-repo packages as the current command, `yarn install` ignores the available root level `node_modules` and re-install them from server instead. Any way I can save time here?

Repo Structure

```
 - node_modules # available already in repo
 - packages/
   - package1
     - node_modules # this to installed/symlink from root node_modules
     - package.json 
   - package2
     - node_modules # this to installed/symlink from root node_modules
     - package.json
```